# Problems with InputStream

Tags: java, inputstream, outputstream

Following is a part of the code snippet that I will be using for my project.

```
public String fetchFromStream()
{
    try
    {
        int charVal;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        while((charVal = inputStream.read()) > 0) {
            sb.append((char)charVal);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        m_log.error("readUntil(..) : " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } finally {
        System.out.println("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Called >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
    }
}
```

Initially the while loop start working pretty fine. But after the probable last character is read from the stream I was expecting to get -1 return value. But this is where my problem starts. The code gets hanged, even the finally block is not executed.

I was debugging this code in Eclipse to see what is actually happening during the run-time. I set a pointer (debug) inside the while loop and was constantly monitoring the StringBuffer getting populated with char values one by one. But suddenly while checking the condition inside the while loop, the debugging control is getting lost and this is the point where the code goes to hangup state !! No exception is thrown as well !!

What is happening here ?

Edit::

This is how I'm getting my InputStream. Basically I'm using Apache Commons Net for Telnet.

```
private TelnetClient getTelnetSession(String hostname, int port)
{
    TelnetClient tc = new TelnetClient();
    try
    {
        tc.connect(hostname, port != 0 ? port : 23);

                    //These are instance variables
        inputStream = tc.getInputStream();
        outputStream = new PrintStream(tc.getOutputStream());

        //More codes...

        return tc;
    } catch (SocketException se)
    {
        m_log.error("getTelnetSession(..) : " + se.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (IOException ioe)
    {
        m_log.error("getTelnetSession(..) : " + ioe.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        m_log.error("getTelnetSession(..) : " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could we see how you initialize the input stream?

Comment: Also don't use StringBuffer. StringBuilder is preferred in 99% of cases (as it states in the Javadoc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29):

> Reads the next byte of data from the input stream. The value byte is returned as an int in the range 0 to 255. If no byte is available because the **end of the stream has been reached, the value -1 is returned**. **This method blocks until input data is available**, the end of the stream is detected, or an exception is thrown.

In simple turns: if your stream ended (e.g. end of file), `read()` returns -1 immediately. However if the stream is still open but JVM is waiting for data (slow disk, socket connection), `read()` will *block* (not really hung).

Where are you getting the stream from? Check out the [`available()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29) - but please do not call it in a loop exhausting CPU.

Finally: casting `int`/`byte` to `char` will only work for ASCII characters, consider using `Reader` on top of `InputStream`.

Comment: Is it possible like there is no byte available but the Stream is still open. I'm a bit confused, I'm just asking.

Comment: So how to be ensured about how many bytes are currently present in the InputStream (if not closed) for the time being ? I saw available() method does not guarantee about the available number of bytes in an open Stream.

Comment: @SubhajitRoy: what do you want to achieve? Looking at your code you want to read the whole stream (up to the end) and convert it to `String`. Have you considered: [`IOUtils.toString(java.io.InputStream)`](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString(java.io.InputStream))?

Comment: I have to achieve something like this:
My InputStream and OutputStream will remain open till the life time of the TelnetSession. Now whenever I have to send any command for the Telnet I have to use the OutputStream and flush it.

After the command is sent, the result (Response) comes to the InputStream. This response is nothing but a new set of available bytes in the InputStream.

So you see my InputStream will not be closed but I have to fetch those new available bytes and ultimately converting to a String which I will be using to show in a .jsp page. 

This is all what I need. :)

Answer (score 2):

read the docs

read() will wait until there is more data on the InputStream if the InputStream is not closed.

I suspect you are doing this with sockets? This is the most common area where this comes up.

"Reads the next byte of data from the input stream. The value byte is returned as an int in the range 0 to 255. If no byte is available because the end of the stream has been reached, the value -1 is returned. This method blocks until input data is available, the end of the stream is detected, or an exception is thrown"

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with the Apache Commons on Android ...
the read() command on the inputstream hangs forever for some reason. And no, it is not just blocking "until data is available" ...
my debugging information shows that there are several 100 chars available() ... yet it just randomly blocks at some read. However, whenever I send something to the telnet server the block is suddenly released and it will continue reading for several chars until it suddenly stops/blocks again at some arbitrary point!

I believe there is some bug within the Apache Commons library! This is really annoying because there isn't a lot that can be done ... no timeout for the read command or anything else ...

EDIT: I was able to get around it ... by setting the TelNetClient.setReaderThread(false) ... obviously there is a bug within the Library that exists as long as a thread handles the input data ... when dispabled it works just fine for me!

Comment: That is a good news. So how are you now reading those bytes from the stream, basically I want to know is what is the condition you are setting in the reading loop.